# Microsoft Azure Backup Server

Tags: azure, backup

I'm going to trial MABS. I've set-up azure Resource Group and this is registered in MABS.

However, when trying to set-up a local storage group, I have no available disks to add? I'm obviously missing something really simple...but what?

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup the Azure backup vault?

I found this guide pretty useful.  It details each step to get it all set up.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/backup-azure-microsoft-azure-backup/

Comment: Yes, I've set-up the azure backup vault...no issues at all. I've now installed MABS on a local VM, I need to set-up a local storage group where the backups are staged before they get sent up to Azure.